# Error uploading file using MSGraph in onedrive business account

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I use Microsoft graph to create a web application that uploads files to OneDrive.
File upload uses upload session.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

uploading a file fails if the upload destination account is a Business account.
The error that occurs is
`{" error ": {" innerError ": {" code ":" invalidToken "}," code ":" unauthenticated "," message ":" This access token is not valid on this endpoint. "}}`.

However, it will succeed if the upload destination is a personal account
By the way, the simple upload will succeed in both business and personal.
Do you know if there are any measures?

The following is the upload procedure.
(1)

```
POST /me/drive/root:/sample.txt:/createUploadSession
Authorization: Bearer {bearer token}
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "item": {
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "name": "sample.txt"
  }
}
```

(2)response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "uploadUrl": "https://our-tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/our_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/aaaa/uploadSession?guid='example'&path='example'&overwrite=False&rename=True&dc=0&tempauth=example",
  "expirationDateTime": "2019-05-24T05:07:08.728Z"
}
```

(3)
Upload bytes to the upload session

```
PUT https://our-tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/our_tenant_onmicrosoft_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/aaaa/uploadSession?guid='example'&path='example'&overwrite=False&rename=True&dc=0&tempauth=example
```

(4) return error

```
HTTP/1.1 401
{"error":{"innerError":{"code":"invalidToken"},"code":"unauthenticated","message":"This access token is not valid on this endpoint."}}
```

By the way, in case of a personal account, uploadUrl of the response is

```
https://api.onedrive.com/rup/example/more~~~
```

Will be back.
I can upload with this path.
UploadUrl is different in the personal account and the business account, is this related to this error?
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When using PUT don't send the token it's not accepted there.

> Including the Authorization header when issuing the PUT call may result in a HTTP 401 Unauthorized response.
>
> The Authorization header and bearer token should only be sent when issuing the POST during the first step. It should be not be included when issueing the PUT.

Comment: When I using PUT, I did not send the token.And The error is Unauthenticated instead of Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved.
The reason is that the HTTP client of the web application has rearranged the query parameter of the URL.
I used faraday of Ruby on Rails, so I changed this.

Comment: I had the same problem with Faraday's query param reordering. There is support to turn off the sorting (https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/pull/1162) which made it work for me